# Showing text in a straight column without using table and having any parent div or styling applied to parent div

Tags: html, css

Its a very simple thing but i am stuck on it.
I have text that is generated dynamically and I want to show it like below without using table

```
text1abc   re:text1
tex2       re:abc
testsfsdf  re:ddd
```

I want to show column 2 at fixed length from column 1 and both column 1 and column 2 are generated like

```
<div>text1abc</div>     <div style="margin-left:20px">re:text1</div>
<div>tex2</div>         <div style="margin-left:20px">re:abc</div>
<div>testsfsdf</div>    <div style="margin-left:20px">re:ddd</div>
```

but this margin left style does not work it shows like

```
text1abc     re:text1
tex2       re:abc
testsfsdfs     re:ddd
```

Comment: You can't get output like that with only those styles. Also, Mr. Alien is right and you can just use a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="content">
  <div> <span>text1abc</span>   re:text1</div>
  <div> <span>tex2</span>       re:abc  </div>
  <div> <span>testsfsdf</span>  re:ddd  </div>
</div>
.content > div > span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%; /* or choose some other value */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are having a tabular data than use tables, there's nothing wrong in using tables, but if you are still redundant to use them and you want to stick with `div` than you can use `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BbY2U/)

```
.table {
    display: table;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.table-row div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: data is coming dynamically and i am generating using razor and there is lots of other data beside this so its not possible to go with this technique.

Comment: @ImranJawaid data is coming along with the `div` tags?

Comment: actually it has other divs above this data as well and i am looping so i cant actually make a parent div like this.

Comment: solution beneath ur solution worked for me .line
{
  width:50%;float:left;
}

Comment: as i cant make parent div :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out  this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/shashibb/SmDvG/

**CSS**

```
.line
{
  width:50%;float:left;
}
```

`You can change the width according to your requirement.`

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <div class="line">text1abc</div><div >re:text1</div>
   <div class="line">tex2</div>         <div >re:abc</div>
   <div class="line">testsfsdf</div><div>re:ddd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually data is comming dynamically line by line so not possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="content">
  <div> <span>text1abc</span>   re:text1</div>
  <div> <span>tex2</span>       re:abc  </div>
  <div> <span>testsfsdf</span>  re:ddd  </div>
</div>
```

```
.content > div > span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%; /* or choose some other value */
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eYUn/4/edit)

Answer (score 0):

By "data is coming in dynamically", do you mean that you can't change the HTML?
If so, you can use this CSS:

```
div:not([style]) {
    float:left;
}

div[style] {
    margin-left:7em !important;
}
```

which will work with the exact HTML you showed. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/XXHWw/).

Sorry for the `!important`, but it's not possible to override an inline style otherwise.

Of course you will need to qualify the selectors a bit further, or you will affect all the divs in the document!